# Python - Configure gevent library on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gevent

I'm newbie in programming and need some help in the following situation.
I want to use [gevent](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/) library on Google App Engine. I'm writing in Python using webapp2.

So the question is how to configure it so that it will work with GAE SDK. 
I've put gevent library files in my projects directory like other libraries which are working well in this project. But when I run my app on local server it says:

> ImportError: No module named greenlet

I've installed it on my computer,

> pip install greenlet -t way/to/python/lib/directory

still it doesn't work

I had similar problem with lxml library, but It was solved after I've written its name in app.yaml. But lxml is preinstalled on GAE as written [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). Although it's not the case with gevent.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt you'll get that to work, given the restrictions on GAE. What is your use case? There are usually much better ways of doing concurrency in a web app.

Comment: I've found some examples on Github where they use gevent with webapp2, think they shoul work but don't know for sure. What I need is to run threads in loop. Just each iteration starts a thread...

Comment: and why do you need gevent for that, rather than simply using the stdlib threading module?

Comment: Because as I understand the next iteration won't start before the current thread finishes it's work, so no actual concurrency takes place here ...

Comment: yep, I found some info about pooling and will try doing it like that. Thanks for help!

Comment: here what is written in official docs: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). So, I think I still need smth like gevent